# How see more of FIbbonaci spiral in python?

Tags: python, fibonacci

How do I see a lot of the fibonacci spiral in Python but still be visible?
Here's the code:

```
import time
import turtle
a = turtle.Turtle()
x = 0
y = 0.01
while 0==0 :
    a.forward(y)
    x = x + y
    a.left(90)
    a.forward(x)
    y = x + y
    a.left(90)
    time.sleep(0.02)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import time
import turtle
a = turtle.Turtle ()
x = 0
y = 10
factor = 0.55
while True:
    a.forward (y)
    x = factor * (x + y)
    a.left(90)
    a.forward (x)
    y = factor * (x + y)
    a.left (90)
    time.sleep (0.02)
```

[image]